# Google Shopping API - where to find merchant id

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-shopping-api

I am trying to set up Google Shopping API and to use it I need to find Merchant #ID

This article is not helpful
[https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/7163092?hl=en#:~:text=To%20find%20your%20Merchant%20ID,then%20find%20your%20merchant%20ID](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/7163092?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20find%20your%20Merchant%20ID,then%20find%20your%20merchant%20ID)

There is no settings link at the top.

We need merchant ID to Use API. It does not work without. I use Google SDK.

Regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 0):

If you open Merchant Center, you will see your account id in the URL. It is the number after "?a="